# How to define a boxed environment using tcolorbox like the following picture?

Tags: tcolorbox

[image]

I tried the following code, but the quotation marks at the top left is not at the right place.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{note}[1][\linewidth]{
    enhanced,
    colback = white,
    boxrule = -1pt,
    sharp corners,
    frame code = {
      \draw [line width = 5pt, blue]
            ([xshift = 0.3cm]frame.north west) --
            (frame.north east) --
            (frame.south east) --
            (frame.south west) -- 
            ([yshift = -0.3cm]frame.north west);  
      \node [scale = 5] at (frame.north west) {``};
    },
    width = #1
}
\begin{document}

\begin{note}[4cm]
  This is a boxed frame.
\end{note}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The quotation marks at top left should havce been at `frame.north west`, but it shifts up.

Comment: You could raise the box containing the quotes like `\raisebox{-1em}{\`\`}` but the problem is that it is behind the white box.

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't help, since the frame is clipped.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{note}[1][\linewidth]{
width = #1, 
sharp corners,
boxed title style={boxrule=0pt,colframe=white},
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-3mm,yshift=-2mm},
colbacktitle=white,
colback=white,
colframe=blue,
coltitle=blue,
enhanced, 
fonttitle=\bfseries\Huge,
title=\vbox to 3mm{\kern.1em\hbox to 0pt{\kern-.2em``}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{note}[4cm] This is a boxed frame \end{note}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much.